# Prevent re-rendering in ReactJS of all childs on onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setupping a simple dashboard to challeging my self with ReactJS, but I have some issues preventing useless re-rendering.

I have a root component called App where I fetch some data.

```
const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [list1, setList1] = useState(null);
    const [list2, setList2] = useState(null);
    const [list3, setList3] = useState(null);
    const [list4, setList4] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = fetchDataInSomeWay();

        const fetchedData = getData(fetchData);
        const list1Data = getList1(fetchData);
        setList1(list1Data);
        setData(fetchedData);
    });

   ...

    { data !== null
        && (
            <Parent
                data={data}
                list1={list1}
                list2={list2}
                list3={list3}
                list4={list4}
            />
};
```

Then I setup a Parent component where I created some Select component and other elements which depend on the values ​​selected by select.
I have a Select element for each list state created with useState();

```
const Google = ({
    data,
    list1,
    list2,
    list3,
    list4,
}) => {
    const [typeValue, setTypeValue] = useState('someValue');
    const [list1Value, setList1Value] = useState(list1[0]);
    const [list2Value, setList2Value] = useState(list2[0]);
    const [list3Value, setList3Value] = useState(list3[0]);
    const [list4Value, setList4Value] = useState(list4[0]);

    const onChangeSelectTypeValue = (value) => {
        setTypeValue(value);
    };

    ...

    const selectTypeValueElement = (
        <SelectElement
            select={selectType}
            value={[typeValue]}
            onChangeValue={onChangeSelectTypeValue}
            values={list1Value}
        />
    );

    ...

    <div className="interactionHeaderChart">
        { selectTypeValueElement }
        ...
    </div>
};
```

Then I have a Select element where I do not store a state, but where option selected is passed to Parent compoment.

```
const SelectElement = ({
    select, value, values, onChangeValue,
}) => {
    ...
    <Select
        ...
        value={value[0]}
        onChange={onChangeValue}
    >
    ...
};
```

Now when I select some option from one Select, state of Parent change and all Childs re-render, all Selects components and also other components which depend on the values ​​selected by select.

Can I prevent all Select components from re-rendering? Can I avoid to re-render all other components which does not depend on the values of option selected?
The fact that the state has changed from the onChange function and not from useEffect() is confusing me and I can not understand how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into shouldComponentUpdate:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Usually, in order to use this with your SelectElement component you will first have to convert it into a Class. You can then add the shouldComponentUpdate function to it and check the previous and next props are the same or not. If they are the same, don't update.

However, if your props are not complex objects, you can actually just recreate your SelectElement as a PureComponent. This will automatically check the props and will not re-render if they're the same.

e.g.

```
class SelectElement extends React.PureComponet {...
```

Comment: Or `React.memo` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for function component.

Comment: @Morris thanks for you answer, but is there a solution without use class? Because one of the challenge is to use Hooks instead of Class. In particular, what I am doing now is to translate Class into Hooks. SelectElement was a PureComponent, before.

Comment: @JakubJanczyk I forgot to mention that. I already tryed to use React.memo with something like `const SelectElement = React.memo(({..}) => {...});,` but also with it all SelectElement were highlighted.

Comment: @lezan that's because `React.memo` works by just checking if properties references are different. In your case props `value={[typeValue]}` and `onChangeValue={onChangeSelectTypeValue}` would be different with every re-render. In the first case because it's new array every time, in the second because function gets re-created. Use `useMemo` and `useCallback` accordingly and wrap your variables/functions to avoid this problem. Let me know if it's clear - I would elaborate in longer answer if necessary.

Comment: @JakubJanczyk thanks for take time to reply. I will check it soon as I can and I will report you the outcome.

Comment: I am reading some documentation and someone point out that in this particular situation useMemo() is not the right hooks to use, but useRef. Here list1, list2, list3, list4 are array of string, not so expensive, I just want to avoid re-rendering. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

you can use memo to avoid re rendering.

**Way 1:**

```
const NestedComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            ContainerComponent
        </div>
    );
};
export default React.memo(NestedComponent);
```

**Way 2:**

```
function ParentComponent(a, b) {
  const childComponent = React.useMemo(() => <ChildComponent posts={a} />, [a]);

  return (
    <>
      {childComponent}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. Let me examine all suggestions you give me and I will report you the outcome.

Comment: Way 1 is not working, as already reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512096/prevent-re-rendering-in-reactjs-of-all-childs-on-onchange-event/61513349?noredirect=1#comment108812926_61512525) and the reason is because values are not primitive, but arrays and functions. Way 2 is not working, still all components are highlitghed.